# summernote adding extra content <p><br></p>

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I am trying to insert a simple div tag with predefine class name into the editor.

I expect to see

```
<div id="btnTimer">SomeText</div>
```

What I am getting is

```
<p><br></p><div id="btnTimer">SomeText</div><p><br></p>
```

I have added a custom button in the editor and click of that button selected content added in the div tag with the id attribute

```
var ui = $.summernote.ui;
   var button = ui.buttonGroup([
       ui.button({
          tooltip: 'Add Timer Text',
          contents: '<i class="icon icon-alarm"></i>',
          click: function () {
              var text = context.invoke('editor.getSelectedText');
              var node = $('<div id="btnTimer">'+text.trim()+'</div>');
              context.invoke('editor.insertNode', node[0]);
          }
       })
   ]);
```

Comment: just a guess: I think the editor inserts everything inside a `<p> ` element and since you can't insert a div inside a p you get the structure you describe. Try sticking to `<span>` (and other inline) elements and check if this resolves your issue.

Comment: @cloned Yeah, it's working with span tag but sometimes font styles have been changed

Comment: then add a style attribute to your span `<span style="font-size: 23px">` (or some class or whatever is easiest.

Comment: hahaha... No, it's not possible because my content was pasted from word file and it's already formated